# Performance comparison of queue vs topic

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

My application sends a JMS for each invocation in a rest api. Using a durable topic destination, I tried benchmarking it and got around 1400 requests/second. I wanted to implement load balancing so I switched to queue instead but upon benchmarking, I only get 400 requests/second. I'm using asynchronous sending btw.

Is queue slower than topic?

Comment: Is your topic messages realy consumed? By default, topics discarts the messages if there are not active consumers. It does not happen with queues.

Comment: Yup both have an active consumer

Comment: If it helps, I'm using a client acknowledgement mode too.

Comment: What broker version are you using?  What client implementation are you using to send and consume the messages?  Are the messages persistent?  Are you measuring the performance from the producer or from the consumer?  If the latter, have you tried scaling up the consumers for the queue use-case to see if you might get a total throughput greater than the topic use-case?  Have you tried ActiveMQ Artemis which implements JMS 2 (which allows shared subscriptions)?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, repeatable example of your issue in play